# Is there a better way to check if user clicked the link from inbox (Laravel url $param to controller)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I want to know if my prospect clicked on the link sent to his email.

So i made this:

My route:

```
Route::get('/audit/{email}/{from?}', 'ProspectPageController@show');
```

This route makes this link: **mysite.com/audit/jhon@mail.com/inbox**

I will send this link to Prospect's email, and if he clicks on it my column will update.

My controller :

```
public function show($email, $stats = null)
{
     if($stats == 'inbox'){
        $prospected= Prospect::where('email', $email)->first();
        $prospected->stats = '1';
        $prospected->save();
     }
    $prospect= Prospect::where('email', $email)->first();
    return view('prospect.show')->with('prospect', $prospect);

}
```

I don't think that this is a good way to do it, is there a better way to make this?

Can i improve this function?

Comment: why use `save()` if you want to update than use `update()` intead of `save()`

Comment: no need to write this line $prospect= Prospect::where('email', $email)->first(); again in the end.

Comment: You can use activate code to perform such action so that user can click button only once from the email box

Answer (score 1):

First generate unique token for each mail and save in table then send link with token :

**Example**

```
token is : 123-456-789
```

link is

```
mysite.com/audit?token=123-456-789
```

In controller you can check with token you can also validate with user if in table you store token and user id. 
my english is not good. i hope you undersatnd answer.